# R shiny, cannot find the function

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny application that contains 2 tabs. In the second tab i run an SQL query to get back a data-frame which i want to post on screen so the user can see. For brevity i have only included the relevant code. Basically the user selects a date range, this goes to the database and pulls the relevant information and returns that information to the server to post to the screen. Currently when run the app i get the error message

> Error: could not find function "report_data"

I would be grateful for any help you could provide

```
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# UI    
# TAB 2 which lets the user select a date range and press the submit button
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
tabPanel("Review Uploaded Data", 
                  # Side Panel with Options
                  fluidRow(
                    column(4, wellPanel(
                      id = "leftPanel",

                      div(id = "Header",
                          h3("Options", align = "center"),
                          tags$hr()
                      ),

                      div(id = "form2",

                          dateRangeInput("dates", label = h3("Entry Date Range")),
                          actionButton("search", "Search Database", class = "btn-primary")

                      )
                    )),

                    column(8, id = "reporttable",
                           # Main Panel shows the uploaded excel document when a user first uploads
                           DT::dataTableOutput("reportTable")

                    )))


#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Server    
# TAB 2 Review Uploaded Data
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


# When User selects a date Range. Run the SQL to pull information for that Date Range
report_data <- observeEvent(input$search, {
  load_data(input$dates)
})  

# Show the summary table
output$reportTable <- DT::renderDataTable(
  DT::datatable(
    report_data (),
    rownames = TRUE,
    options = list(searching = FALSE, lengthChange = FALSE, scrollX = FALSE)
  ))
```

This function is the function that goes to the database and returns the dataframe based on the users selections of a date range.

```
# Load the data from the MYSQL table
load_data <- function(dateRange) {
  # Connect to the database
  db <- dbConnect(MySQL(), dbname = databaseName, host =  options()$mysql$host, 
              port = options()$mysql$port, user = options()$mysql$user, 
              password = options()$mysql$password)


  start_date <- dateRange[1] 
  end_date <- dateRange[2]

  # Construct the fetching query
  query <- sprintf("SELECT USER, COUNT(*) as records FROM %s
WHERE ENTRY_DATE BETWEEN '%s' AND '%s' GROUP BY 1", table, start_date,     end_date)

  # Submit the fetch query and disconnect
  data <- dbGetQuery(db, query)
  dbDisconnect(db)
  names(data) <- c("User", "records")

  return(data)
}
```

Comment: you need `eventReactive` instead of `observeEvent` because observeEvent - return nothing

Comment: Thank you so much, i was scratching my head for ages over this. Please put it as an answer and i will mark it immediately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There some differences between `eventReactive` and  `observeEvent`

One of the important (my mind ) that `observeEvent` not return values

as told in help :

> Use observeEvent whenever you want to perform an action in response to
>   an event. (Note that "recalculate a value" does not generally count as
>   performing an action–see eventReactive for that.)
>
> Use eventReactive to create a calculated value that only updates in
>   response to an event.

So you can simply use `eventReactive`

```
report_data <- eventReactive(input$search, {
  load_data(input$dates)
})
```

Or create `reactiveValues` and change it in `observeEvent` ( sometimes it better -- when condition not simple )

```
report_data <- reactiveValues(data_1=NULL)
observeEvent(input$search, {
  report_data$data_1<-load_data(input$dates)
})
```

and then use `report_data$data_1`